# Extracting Netcdf climate data for multiple locations at different times using R?

Tags: r, netcdf, climate

I have daily sea surface temperature and air temperature data from 1980 to 2018. How do I extract values for multiple (up to 100) specific locations at different dates in one go to csv. Right now I can only extract one location at a time.

How can it be done in bulk in R?

Answer (score 4):

Here is some example code for R. I think there are many examples out there.

```
library(raster)
b <- brick("climfile.nc")
points <- shapefile("ptsfile.shp") 
d <- extract(b, points)
write.csv(d, "file.csv", rownames=FALSE)
```